# Error with CakePHP - Notice (8): Undefined variable: uri

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm starting with `CakePHP` and I am following the blog tutorial from the official page.

But when I reach to the section **Creating Post Views** of the tutorial(http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html), I get an error.

After creating the mentioned files on the tutorial, I direct the browser to `http://mypersonalspace.host.mobi/posts/index` to see if its working correctly. But the page displays the next error:

**Notice (8): Undefined variable: uri [CORE/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php, line 247]**

I do not know what to do because I have not touched that file. I even moved all my CakePHP installation to the *httpdocs* root folder, because I had it originally in a sub-folder named *framework*. I have checked the files looking for typos or something, but I have no clue.

Can you help me please?

I am using the version 2.2.0 of `CakePHP` and my webserver is hosted in a subdomain(`http://mypersonalspace.host.mobi`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `$uri` isn't defined. Check this in `CORE/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php` at line `247`.

Or put before `247` line:

```
$uri = isset($uri) ? $uri : '';
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But now i have another question. In the tutorial, when going to the page, it says that i'm supposed to see the entries stored in my database, but i get the same welcome page after installing the framework. Am i missing something? Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know, I've never used CakePHP.